# RabbitMQ Brokerunreachable exception timeout intermittently from a machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq

We have 11 windows webapp machines running IIS. These send messages to rabbitMQ server for tasks. We are using rabbit for basic work queue functionality. For each message publish a new connection and a channel is created. Pretty much like in the tutorial here - https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html

This is working great most of the time, but in production, sporadically from a different machine every time once or twice a day, we start getting this exception on ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection.

```
[BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable]
RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection():56

[TimeoutException: Connection to amqp://machinename.domain.net:5672 timed out]
    RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.Connect(TcpClient socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Int32 timeout):65
    RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func2 socketFactory, Int32 timeout):52
    RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.ProtocolBase.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, Int32 timeout):8
    RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection():45
```

Which is causing message loss. I have been investigating max concurrent connections for each machine setting - but did not lead me anywhere. This does not coincide with our peak traffic either. The most interesting clue i have is that it happens in bursts and when it happens it is ONLY happening to one out of the 11 machines publishing messages to the queue at a time.

I am using rabbitmq dot net client.

Any ideas or pointers on what could be the possible cause?

Answer (score 0):

Probably some sort of packet loss? Why not Try...Catch..Retry?

Do a `ping RabbitServerHostName -t` (where RabbitServerHostName is the server where you have Rabbit installed) in a command window and see after couple of days how many packet losses you have.

Answer (score 0):

Because of all the packet drops and network instability issues, it is almost always a recommended approach to retry your connection creation. EasyNetQ library does it really well. It is however not very complex to implement your own timer based retry when you get this exception until connection is established.